# Using inspect on the HTML doesn't highlight custom component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components, web-inspector

I'm trying to inspect a simple custom component made in Ionic 3. When i inspect it, chrome doesn't highlight the area of the custom component. It only highlights the area if i select a element inside the custom component.

To help u understand it better i've put screenshots of the problem im facing.

The picture shows a div element inside the custom element star-rating, which is being highlighted. This is okay.

[image: selecting div inside custom component]

But now when i select star-rating element(which is the custom component) , it doesn't highlight anything as you can see in the image below.

[[image: selecting custom component[2]]

This is causing a problem when i want to add border to the custom component like this.

```
star-rating{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:0px;
}
```

resulting in

[image]

I could add border in the div tag instead to solve this problem. But i don't want to do that because I want to use this selector for adding css to the last child of star-rating.

```
star-rating:last-child{
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `custom-elements` use `display: inline` by default. You can add the following styles to your component:

```
:host {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Great!! Glad to know it was so simple. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Hi, actually I had to do something like this `star-rating{
        display:block;
    }`
on the component which is using star-rating. It didn't work directly using the `:host{ display:block } ` on star-rating.scss. Do you know any reason why?

Comment: @user2049132, it should work. can you create a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqggny)?

Comment: I could not save changes in the link you sent so i forked it. Here it is with with :host added to it. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7yrtyj)

Comment: @user2049132, you don't need a comma after `h1 { 
              font-family: Lato; 
            }`, remove it and it will work fine)

Comment: Yeah! You're right that fixes it in the demo. But im actually using scss file and it doesn't seem to work if i use the scss file(I'm using Ionic). The contents of mycomponent.scss looks like ` restaurant-card {    :host         display:block;  } }`. This doesn't work. I can't show this on demo because stackblitz doesn't support scss yet.

Comment: @user2049132, sorry, can't help there. It's a different issue. It's the right and working approach as I showed in the plunker. If it's not working for you with SASS then it's something else

Comment: Thank you for helping anyways :). Yes you are right the issue is solved using `display: block;`. Not being able to use `:host` in scss is a different issue.

Comment: I have found a fix it works if i do this in the mycomponent.scss `my-component{ display:block; h1{ color:#000 } }`. I don't need to use `:host`. Using component selector my-component directly fixes it.