# Components angular 2 size are wrong

Tags: javascript, angular

I got an issue with component angular2. 
The size of component didn't change when i rerender by ngFor. Here my code:

```
<app-viewscreen #viewscreen 
                *ngFor = "let viewScreenInfo of viewScreenList" 
                [viewScreenInfo]="viewScreenInfo">
</app-viewscreen>
```

The component will have size of parent component so one is show, the other is out of range like this.
[image: Issue1]
[image: Issue2]

How i can make the components have been rendered doesn't have size, only element HTML like div inside component have or make all components fixed with parent not out of range anymore.

Sorry for my bad english. Please help me.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your question but if you want your component to act as a `div` you just need to set `:host{display:block;}` in the CSS of your component.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693973/using-inspect-on-the-html-doesnt-highlight-custom-component/45694000#45694000